# Returning DISTINCT rows from database query

Tags: sql, distinct

I am fairly new to SQL so apologies if there is a simple solution to this.

I have this piece of SQL that performs a join on 3 tables.

```
    SELECT a.group_leader, b.forum_name
    FROM flightuser_group a
    INNER JOIN flightacl_groups c ON a.group_id = c.group_id
    JOIN flightforums b ON c.forum_id = b.forum_id
    WHERE a.user_id = '60'
    ORDER BY a.group_leader DESC
```

This query returns this:

```
    group_leader   forum_name
    1              tmpSQJ
    0              jobby7
    0              jobby5
    0              tmpSQJ
```

I am trying to only keep the first tmpSQJ entry and remove the second but cannot determine where the DISTICT clause goes.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you using? MySQL? MS SQL 2005? You probably want a TOP clause, not a distinct.

Comment: Hello rajah9. I am using MySQL

Comment: The reason you are getting multiple tmpSQJ records is because SQL doesn't know which column makes it distinct. In your example, "1, tmpSQJ" and "0, tmpSQJ" are different rows (because the group_leader is different). One way to get only one tmpSQJ is to update the group_leader in the flightuser_group table to the same number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
 SELECT MAX(a.group_leader), b.forum_name     
 FROM flightuser_group a     INNER JOIN flightacl_groups c ON a.group_id = c.group_id   
   JOIN flightforums b ON c.forum_id = b.forum_id    
    WHERE a.user_id = '60' 
    GROUP BY  b.forum_name  
    ORDER BY a.group_leader DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, add a `LIMIT 1` after the `ORDER BY`.

For MS SQL, add a `TOP 1` after the `SELECT`.

These two flavors will get you only the first record in the recordset.

Comment: Hello rajah9. Using Limit 1 gives me only 1 record I need all records except the last duplicate.

Comment: Does my comment on your Q make sense, @SQJ? Pls post another comment if it's not clear.

Comment: Hello rajah9. Your comment does make sense. Unfortunately I am unable to update the flightuser_group table as the table is managed outside of my control I can only read from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a GROUP BY which essentially behaves the same:

```
SELECT a.group_leader, b.forum_name
FROM flightuser_group a
INNER JOIN flightacl_groups c ON a.group_id = c.group_id
JOIN flightforums b ON c.forum_id = b.forum_id
WHERE a.user_id = '60'
GROUP BY b.forum_name
ORDER BY a.group_leader DESC
```

You could also look at using "**INNER JOIN**" for ***flightforums***

Comment: The above query doesn't work. Since you don't have group_leader in group by and if you try to add to group by still it will return all the rows since the group_leader is different even though the forum_name is same